# how to generate custom collection type in .Net from WSDL?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am running a custom application that imports WSDLs and generates C# source code, using WSDLImporter class to read in contracts.

XSD sequence types are translated into native arrays.  What options can I set in order to be able to generate custom collection types?

Schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="getAllSourcesResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" 
            name="return" type="tns:Source"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

becomes code:

```
public partial class getAllSourcesResponse
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return",
        Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public PaymentSource[] @return;

    public getAllSourcesResponse()
    {
    }

    public getAllSourcesResponse(Source[] @return)
    {
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}
```

I looked into SvcUtil.exe code, it appears to do the following, but it does not seem to make any difference in what code my application produces.

```
WsdlImporter importer = ... 

XsdDataContractImporter contractImporter = 
    new XsdDataContractImporter(codeCompileUnit); 

ImportOptions importOptions = new ImportOptions();
importOptions.ReferencedCollectionTypes.Add(
    typeof(System.Collections.Generic.IList<>)); 

contractImporter.Options = importOptions; 

importer.State.Add(typeof(XsdDataContractImporter), contractImporter);
```

---

@CasperOne, this schema snippet

```
<xs:complexType name="getClassesForPackageResponse">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

generates a string[] type:

```
public partial class getClassesForPackageResponse
{
    public string[] @return;
    public getClassesForPackageResponse() {}

    public getClassesForPackageResponse(string[] @return)
    {    this.@return = @return;    }
}
```

This does not cause string collection to use List:

```
ImportOptions importOptions = new ImportOptions();
importOptions.ReferencedCollectionTypes.Add(
    typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<string>));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I believe you need to indicate a collection implementation, not just the interface, so that means `List<T>` instead of `IList<T>` (although you can certainly try it with the interface).

Second, you need to specify the type parameter T:

```
ImportOptions importOptions = new ImportOptions();

importOptions.ReferencedCollectionTypes.Add(
    typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<getAllSourcesResponse>));
```

As it was, you were passing the open generic type, which will not match with anything when the importer is trying to resolve the collection.

Comment: The tool that's doing the conversion does not know about the types used in WSDLs. I can not specify "List<getAllSourcesResponse>" because getAllSourcesResponse is not a valid type or namespace, it causes a compile error.

Comment: I also tried "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>", but I still get "string[] " in the generated code, instead of "List<string>"

Comment: @janya: Well, why not get the schema for the getAllSourcesResponse ^first^ and get the type representation of that, and then import the contract definition?

Comment: @casperOne: true enough, I'll do that, thank you.  
Any ideas why adding List<string> to the ReferencedCollectionTypes still gets string[] in generated code?

Comment: @janya: Because it can't match a string type to the schema definition.   If it was a sequence of string elements, then it would be used as a string, but its a sequence of getAllSourcesResponse elements.

Comment: @casperOne: how do I get a type representation from the imported schema?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this while trying to figure out how to do this in Mono's WSDL importer.

After reading some MSDN docs and playing around a bit with this, I got it working like this, using .NET 4.5:

```
    var importer = new WsdlImporter (mset);
    var xsdImporter = new XsdDataContractImporter ();
    var options = new ImportOptions ();
    options.ReferencedCollectionTypes.Add (typeof (LinkedList<>));
    xsdImporter.Options = options;
    importer.State.Add (typeof (XsdDataContractImporter), xsdImporter);
```

You can also specify specific generic instance types such as `List<int>`.

This is also documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702680.aspx